# Error: variable was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am getting the below error, when i am trying to compile code below.

```
Error: main.cpp: In function "int main()":
       main.cpp:6: error: "display" was not declared in this scope
```

**test1.h**

```
#include<iostream.h>
class Test
{
  public:
    friend int display();
};
```

**test1.cpp:**

```
#include<iostream.h>
int  display()
{
    cout<<"Hello:In test.cc"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<test1.h>
int main()
{
 display();
 return 0;
}
```

Strange thing is I am able to compile in unix successfully. 
I am using gcc and g++ compiler

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the declaration for the function before declaring it as friend.
The declaration as friend does not qualify as actual function declaration as per the standard.

**C++11 standard §7.3.1.2 [namespace.memdef]:**
**Para 3:**

> [...] If a `friend` declaration in a nonlocal class first declares a class or function the friend class or function is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. **The name of the friend is not found by unqualified lookup or by qualified lookup until a matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope** (either before or after the class definition granting friendship). [...]

```
#include<iostream.h>
class Test
{
  public:
    friend int display();  <------------- Only a friend declaration not actual declaration
};
```

You need:

```
#include<iostream.h>
int display();            <------- Actual declaration
class Test
{
  public:
    friend int display();     <------- Friend declaration 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. It looks like the `friend` declaration for `display()` in `test1.h` counts as an actual function declaration in g++.

I do not think the standard actually enforces this, so you probably want to add a proper declaration for `display()` in `test1.h`:

```
#include <iostream>

int display();

class Test
{
public:
    friend int display();
};
```

Comment: Hi, If we declare it outside the class then compiler will treat this function as normal function not the friend function of the class Test and will not be able to access the member variable of that class.. it will give the error

Comment: @Akhirul, this should not happen, unless you removed the `friend` declaration while adding the proper one.

Comment: @AkhirulIslam: The function declaration outside the class tells the compiler that there exists a function by this name and it will take this parameters, while the declaration inside the class tells the compiler that this function is friend to this class. Both are unrelated, there is no error. Have you even tried it?

Comment: Please check my below code:                      #include<iostream.h>
int display();
class Test
{
 int a;
 public:
        Test();
        friend int display();
};                                                                   #include<iostream.h>
#include "test1.h"
using namespace std;
int display()
{
        cout<<"Hello:In test.cc"<<a<<endl;
        return 0;
}
Test::Test()
{
 a=12;
}                                                               When i am trying to compile i am getting the the error            error: âaâ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Akhirul, `friend` means that private and protected members of `Test` can be accessed by `display()`, but you still need to pass an instance of `Test` to `display()` in order for it to access its `a` member. `friend` functions cannot summon members out of thin air.